# Which contemporary philosophers explicitly engage with Nietzsche's statement that "God is dead"?

Tags: theology, nietzsche, aesthetics, nihilism

Which contemporary theorists, especially of art or poetry, explicitly and deliberately engage with Nietzsche's statement that "[God is dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_is_dead)"?

Obviously Nietzsche has had a huge influence on post / modernity, and with it the literature and art of the time. But what's really ***new***, with respect to this particular statement of Nietzsche / his madman?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken then Arno Kleinbeckel referred to him in his 2009 "Seufzende Sterne". It is not poetry but rather a poetic contestation of the current zeitgeist.

Philosophical works are numerous. For a rather unusual approach I recommend Edith Düsing's "Nietzsches Denkweg" (Fink Wilhelm 2006) or Harald Seubert's "Zwischen erstem und anderem Anfang" (Köln: Böhlau, 2000).